# Mocha + SeleniumJS + PhantomJS retrieves timeout

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha + SeleniumJS using webdriver(not standalone installation) and Mocha as test framework
Scripts are running ok on MAC OS, but when I try to use Windows server they start failing.

**This is the script that tries to create a new webdriver session and navigates to the URL sent as parameter.**

```
*exports.goToPage = function(Url) {
        var capabilities = {
        'browserName' : 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.binary.path' : './node_modules/.bin/phantomjs.cmd',
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent' : +userAgent,
        'phantomjs.cli.args' : ['--debug=true --webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG --port=30000']
        };
        browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
    }
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8000);
    browserOpen = 1;
    return browser.get(Url).then(function() {
        //opts.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        //driver = new ChromeDriver( options );
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
};*
```

**The script is run using:**

mocha Frontend/test/categoriesTest.js

*Error:*

```
Uncaught Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://10.11.100.211:52242/

     at Error (<anonymous>)
     at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1552:9)
     at net.js:441:14


==== async task ====
 WebDriver.createSession() at Object.exports.goToPage (C:\J\dev-smoke-tests\functionalAPI.js:35:83) 
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\J\dev-smoke-tests\Frontend\test\categoriesTest.js:24:7)
```

Comment: Not related to the issue but `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8000);` a pretty large wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usingServer() a url location to a server for your WebDriver. If you are not planing to use custom server then I recommend removing it.

Here is what the official documentation says about it:

> Sets the URL of a remote WebDriver server to use. Once a remote URL has been specified, the builder direct all new clients to that server. If this method is never called, the Builder will attempt to create all clients locally.
>
> As an alternative to this method, you may also set the SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL environment variable.